# cannot run program "Rscript"

Tags: r, shell, hadoop, oozie, sparkr

hi i am running sparkR job with oozie .When i run the oozie job it shows cannot find Rscript error.the error details is below

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, ip-172-31-42-124.us-west-2.compute.internal): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD$.createRProcess(RRDD.scala:387)
at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD$.createRWorker(RRDD.scala:403)
at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.BaseRRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 11 more
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Rscript added in your system path.

In windows for example its location is

`C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin`

You have to add the path of `Rscript.exe` in you sytem path in environment variables.

Comment: how to set the enivronment variable

Comment: for linux http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path for windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows which os you are working in

Comment: i sets this export=/usr/lib64/R/bin.. still i am getting same error only

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path use this then..

Comment: `$ echo $PATH` use this to check if its added correctly